# How to do rake db:migrate:reset using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano3

I am using capistrano for deploying my rails app to digitalocean server. I have came into a situation where I need to run `rake db:migrate:reset` and `rake db:reset`.. I have done it in development and it worked. But can I do it using capistrano in production?

Here is my deploy.rb

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.5.0'

set :application, 'appname'
set :repo_url, 'myrepo.git'

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/myapp'

set :linked_files, %w{config/application.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

# Default value for :scm is :git
# set :scm, :git

# Default value for :format is :airbrussh.
# set :format, :airbrussh

# You can configure the Airbrussh format using :format_options.
# These are the defaults.
# set :format_options, command_output: true, log_file: 'log/capistrano.log', color: :auto, truncate: :auto

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
# set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'public/system')

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
# set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install [this gem](https://github.com/dei79/capistrano-rails-collection) to your project in order to add capistrano recipes to handle database commands

Then, you just need to run `cap production rails:rake:db:reset`

Comment: I tried `gem 'capistrano-rails-db'` and it shows a permission error when running the command. I tried this one as well but didnt work in my case. How can I run it manually so that I can add sudo before the comand which might fix the permission error I have now?

Comment: What's your permission issue ? Is it SSH or MySQL ? Does your MySQL user has correct rights on your production database ?

Comment: its ssh.. Actually I was fololwing this video tutoria https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04 l for deploying.. For creating database its doing manually in that video and not by rake task and it worked for mee..For just migrating capistrano works aswell. But if I try to recreate using capistrano  my application shows permission error when creating database like this. I fixed it by removing all releases and redeploying so that I wont have to drop and recreated the database from server itself..But still i think its not a clean solution always to do like this